# Let $A$ be a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and $c > \lim\sup A$. Show that only finitely many terms of $A$ are greater than or equal to $c$.

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I need to show that at most finitely many terms of this sequence are greater than or equal to $c$.

I don't know if it is the wording of the problem but I don't know what this is asking me to do. Help on this would be amazing! And thank you in advance.

Comment: It's asking you to show that there aren't infinitely many members of $A$ that are greater than or equal to $c$. Could you be more specific about what's confusing you? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the problem means:

You have that $A=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded sequence. That it is bounded means that $|x_i|\leq K$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots$, and for some constant $K>0$.

You then take the $\limsup$ of this sequence. You can define this in different ways, but let me know if you feel shaky about this.

So let $c>\limsup A$ be some constant. You need to prove that only a finite number of elements from $A$ can be larger than $c$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you, perhaps, need a more intuitive understanding of $\limsup_{n\to\infty} s_n=s$.

[I would much prefer to write it this way than the way you did, since then you can relate to what you remember about sequence limits.]

The phrase  $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n=s$ can be thought of in the following way when $s$ is a finite number.  Instead of the $\epsilon$, $N$ version imagine it this way:

> **1.**  $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n=s$ is equivalent to saying that if you choose
>   any numbers $u$  and $v$ with $u<s< v$ then the inequality $$u< s_n < v$$ fails for only
>   the first few terms of the sequence [i.e., with only finitely many
>   exceptions].

In the version you would have learned we always used $u=s-\epsilon$ and $v=s+\epsilon$ but if you are addicted to using $\epsilon$ all the time you get messy details sometimes and miss out on the intuition as well.

Then the limsup and liminf versions are just *half* of this, like right and left hand continuity is half of continuity, and like almost every mathematical idea involving real numbers gets split into a "one-sided" version.

> **2.**  $\limsup_{n\to\infty} s_n\leq s$ is equivalent to saying that if you choose
>   any number $v$ with  $ s< v$ then the inequality $$ s_n < v$$ fails for only
>   the first few terms of the sequence [i.e., with only finitely many
>   exceptions].

.

> **3.**  $\liminf_{n\to\infty} s_n\geq s$ is equivalent to saying that if you choose
>   any number $u$ with  $u<s $ then the inequality $$u< s_n  $$ fails for only
>   the first few terms of the sequence [i.e., with only finitely many
>   exceptions].